# PHP replace characters except the HTML tags

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, html-parsing

I need to replace the characters `0,1,2,...,9` with `\xD9\xA0,\xD9\xA1,\xD9\xA2,...,\xD9\xA9` in a string. This string comes from the CKEditor so it may contains html tags. Using the following code

```
$body = str_replace("1", "\xD9\xA1", $body);
```

it replaces every `1` with `\xD9\xA1` so it effects the tag `<h1>` and also `<table border="1">` while I only need to replace the numbers in the body not the tags.

The tags that contain numbers are `<h0><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6>` and `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` and `border` of table tag.

How do I can replace the numbers with the above symbols  while it won't effect the `<h0><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6>`and `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` and `border` ?

Comment: Never use regex on html. You need to use a parser http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1916721

Comment: You need to parse the HTML and perform the replacement only on textnodes.

Comment: I've never used any parser, I would be appreciated if you give me more details

Comment: Look at htmlparsing.com for starters, or this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't use regex to process html, however if you still want to use a regex you could use the discard pattern with a regex like this:

```
<.*?>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|1
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/yS2jI4/1)**

The idea behind this regex is to skip whatever it is within `<...>` but match the rest. So, it will only match the number `1` that are not within html tags. Once again, I'd use a html parser instead.

Php code

```
$re = "/<.*?>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|1/"; 
$str = "<h0><h1><h2><h3>\n<table border=\"1\">\n1\n"; 
$subst = "\xD9\xA1"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Thanks alot your code works. My website is based on Drupal, So if I want to use a parser I need to install its module on Drupal, it needs a few libraries so I guess using a simple code like yours is much more effective. thanks again